Whatsapp Embed Form: Invalid stepID provided
In the step Create or select your WhatsApp Business Account, after selecting the phone number and pressing "next" you will get a blank page breaking the flow.
The console shows this error:
ErrorUtils caught an error:
Invalid stepID provided
Subsequent non-fatal errors won't be logged; see https://fburl.com/debugjs.
We thinks is a facebook javascript sdk bug affecting only apps that are on develop mode. I tried another website that is live and it works with the same code.
